# How to create a component which have 50% of the background color in Vue

Tags: css, background-color, bootstrap-vue

I am working on bootstrap-vue. I need to build a component which has 50% of the `background-color` and rest blank (vertically). The component should occupy 100% of the screen after the navigation bar, and it should have 50% This component will have different sub-components.

Something like this, **But a straight line separating them.** **(just like Red Line)**

[image]

I have tried adding height and background-color manually. It some how, worked. But, I am looking to do it in bootstrap-vue.

Here is the basic code:
CardGrouper.vue:

```
<template lang="html">

  <div class="h-100" >
    <h1>card-grouper Component</h1>
    <div class="h-50" style=" background-color: #C8544F">
      Height 50%
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script lang="js">
  export default  {
    name: 'CardGrouper',
    props: [],
    mounted() {

    },
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    methods: {

    },
    computed: {

    }
}
</script>

<style scoped >

</style>
```

I also tried different classes of bootstrap to add 50% background. But It did'nt work.

How is it possible to do it using Bootstrap-vue and vue.
Specifically, I am looking for a pure bootstrap solution. since I am developing a responsive application.

Thanks for the help

Comment: do you mean 50% opacity? do you mean left side has background-color: red; and right side has background-color: none? 50% top? 50% bottom? please evaluate a little more and show us what you`ve tried

Comment: Made the edits. Thank you for letting me know :)

Comment: I still dont know what you mean with 50% background...do you mean 50% opacity of the original color?

Comment: Two Different colors. Example blue and white. Blue color 50% of the height. But its a background color. and white covers rest of the 50% height in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using linear gradients:

```css
.full{
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 50%, yellow 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="full"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked :)
apologies for not mentioning the question clearly!